# Update multiple Qt models based on a single data source

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2

I want to trigger multiple models updates and thus multiple views updates based on a raw data source update (like a list of objects). How would the mapping between the data and the multiple models work ?

For example:

I have a list of multiple `Measurements` which contain attributes like `size`, `color` and `weight`

- One model is used as an interface with a `QListView` that displays only the `size` of all the `Measurements`
- One model is used as an interface with a `QTableView` that displays the `size` and the `color` of all the Measurements
- etc.

Then I trigger an update on my raw data. It can come from one of the connected models mentionned above or from an outside update. How to prepend this change to all my associated models ?

I am using python with Pyside2 but the answer can be in C++

Comment: I'd consider to implement a single QAbstractListModel to provide all the data (via roles), and then use simple proxy models (QIdentityProxyModel subclasses) to map that data to the columns/roles (mainly Qt::DisplayRole) as needed for respective views.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll look into this direction, thanks. You can post your comment as an answer and I'll upvote it and accept if it happens to solve this problem.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld I think I should implement a QAbstractTableModel instead, to store different attributes in differents columns ? Or is the QAbstractListModel capable of doing that using roles ?

Comment: It would depend on the use case. For most QML applications, you'd use a QAbstractListModel-derived model, but for widget based applications using multiple columns is more common. Seeing that the question mentions QTableView, I'd say using a QAbstractTableModel as a basis would make sense. The proxy can then just be a QSortFilterProxyModel that filters out some columns.

Comment: `QStandardItemModel` is normally the model of choice. Then in the view you decide which columns should be shown. No need to bother with abstract models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @Frank Osterfeld said in his comment, it is possible to store all your data in a model (`QAbstractTableModel` in my case) and then filter out the columns that you don't need in your respective views.

For this I've used a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and overrided the `filterAcceptsColumn()` method.

Here is an example:

```
class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = []
    ... # here are all the things you usually define in an abstract model

class MyProxyModelA(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsColumn(self, source_column: int, source_parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        """ This filters any column that returns true """
        return source_column != 2

class MyProxyModelB(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsColumn(self, source_column: int, source_parent: QModelIndex) -> bool:
        """ This filters any column that returns true """
        return source_column == 2
```

And in my views:

```
model = MyModel()  # I put this here for the sake of this example

class MyWidgetA(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.table = QTableView()

        self.proxy = MyProxyModelA()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(model)

        self.table.setModel(self.proxy)

        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.table)


class MyWidgetB(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.table = QTableView()

        self.proxy = MyProxyModelB()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(model)

        self.table.setModel(self.proxy)

        self.ui.layout.addWidget(self.table)
```

And now you can benefit from the automatic sync of your model and your views whenever you modify it through `MyWidgetA` or `MyWidgetB`